# Upper Incomplete Gamma Function of order 0 in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, gamma-function

I am trying to implement the upper incomplete gamma function of order zero in Python. Normally we use `gammaincc` function but according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincc.html#scipy.special.gammaincc),it's defined only for positive **a**. Is there any way to implement it in python for a=0 case? Thanks.

Comment: No, because Gamma(0) diverges. There's good reason it's defined only for positive `a`.

Comment: I am not trying to implement regularized upper incomplete gamma function but the standard function which is not scaled by dividing it by Gamma(a). It definitely exists. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B0,+0.1%5D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SciPy implements the *regularized* incomplete gamma function, the one with division by Gamma(a). This division makes no sense when a=0, but the non-regularized upper gamma still makes sense. Unfortunately there is no flag like `regularized=False` in SciPy.

However, in the special case `a=0` the upper incomplete gamma function agrees with the exponential integral [`exp1`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.exp1.html#scipy.special.exp1) which is available in SciPy:

```
>>> from scipy.special import exp1
>>> exp1(1.3)
0.13545095784912914
```

(Compare to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma(0,%201.3))).

Alternatively, the [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/expintegrals.html#mpmath.gammainc) library computes non-regularized incomplete gammas by default.

```
>>> import mpmath
>>> mpmath.gammainc(0, 1.3)
mpf('0.13545095784912914')
```

Comment: One can also use "expn(x)" if using minus sign twice looks cumbersome!

Comment: @Prav001, I think you mean either `expn(1, x)` or `exp1(x)`.